# Как сохранять и получать информацию из JSON файла C#?

Tags: c#, json

как можно сохранять и получать информацию из JSON файла на C# используя Newtonsoft.Json? (int, string)

Comment: `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<тип>(json);`, обратно: `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(объект);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если работаете с .NET 5+, то лучше использовать Json сериализатор от Microsoft, пространства имён `System.Text.Json`.

- Документация [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).
- Документация [System.Text.Json](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0).

Содержимое файла test.json:

```
{
  "stringValue": "old value",
  "numberValue": 2022
}
```

Использование `Newtonsoft.Json` ниже:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Test
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            const string filepath = @"C:\Users\Jagailo\Desktop\test.json";

            // Чтение файла
            var json = File.ReadAllText(filepath);

            // Десериализация строки в объект
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileModel>(json);

            // Изменение данных
            data.StringValue = "new value";
            data.IntValue++;

            // Сериализация объекта в строку
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

            // Сохранение строки в файл
            File.WriteAllText(filepath, json);
        }
    }

    public class FileModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("stringValue")]
        public string StringValue { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("numberValue")]
        public int IntValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: А сеализатор от Майкрософт работать может на .NET 4.7.2?

Comment: Может, но для .NET Framework лучше использовать Newtonsoft.Json